# Not wanted automatic merging master branch in Git

Tags: git, version-control, merge, git-merge

we are a smal group having two branches in main remote repository - origin/master (for stable code) and origin/development (for stable changes).
Every one of us has cloned the repository, to get connected master-origin/master branches and created development branch by 'git checkout -b development origin/development'. When we are working, we are branching the 'development' branch (e.g. 'development-idea1' branch) After making some working changes which we want to share with others we do exactly this:

```
git checkout development
git pull
git merge development-idea1
git push
git checkout development-idea1
git merge development
```

But after few days one of us wanted to update master, but Git said 'its up to date'. These two commands

```
'git diff --name-status development..origin/development'
'git diff --name-status development..origin/master'
```

gave us exactly the same...
Can you recognize, where is the problem?

Thank you in advance.

EDIT:
This is our tree

```
* 9bf5667 (origin/dev) clean up
*   eead2c5 Merge branch 'dev-vojta' into dev
|\  
| * fb58c33 new version
* | 88d8a54 Remove debug code.
* | 3dd7c47 processing
|/  
| * 0f9a231 (HEAD, dev-report) small report changes
| * b5d4618 more minilog lines
|/  
* ed845e6 (origin/master, origin/HEAD, master, dev-tomas, dev) trace2 new
*   5cde965 Merge branch 'dev-vojta' into dev
|\  
| * cdbc59c trace new
* |   3ac0125 Merge branch 'dev-vojta' into dev
|\ \  
| |/  
| * 737ae3f new trace
* |   fa1de24 Merge branch 'dev' of /hit/kit-git into dev
|\ \  
| * | d386248 minor changes across the pipeline
| * | 1da7a45 germinate
* | | fb9b397 new trace
* | |   6a54136 Merge branch 'dev-vojta' into dev
|\ \ \  
| |/ /  
|/| /   
| |/    
| * 6558502 new
* | b0dc15f clean up and germlines
* |   91bc91b Merge branch 'dev-nikos' into dev
|\ \  
| * | b9d65f5 hit and process work
* | |   2f9c8a0 Merge branch 'dev' of /hit/kit-git into dev
|\ \ \  
| |/ /  
|/| /   
| |/    
| *   5c0abe6 new trace Merge branch 'dev-vojta' into dev
| |\  
| | * 56b097c new trace
| * | af4c3ef .gitignore - only fasta and extra files included
| * | 8643645 test ''git_shell.sh' automatic script
| * | e900033 wmd report debug messages deleted
| * | 41aae9d .gitignore -  germlines/arrest.v-quest.refdir file separation wmd.pl - report subroutine basics
| * |   1b350f6 Merge branch 'dev' into dev-tomas
| |\ \  
| | |/  
| * | 1711df5 .gitignore - added folders 'germlines/' and 'scenarios/' wmd.pl - basic report subroutine
```

Comment: `git pull` without any parameters might have merged master into development.

Comment: It can be useful to provide us the result of `git log --graph --oneline --decorate --all -30`. With the graph it will be easier to understand what happens

Comment: EDIT: 'git log --graph --oneline --decorate --all -30' added